# How to send a response/data from app.js file to routes file in express framework?

Tags: html, node.js, express

In app.js file,

```
  app.get('/query:arg1/:arg2',function(req,res){
   path.getDetails(req,res);
  }
```

Here path is separate js file which is having getDetails function which in turn gives a response data.

Now I want to send the path.getDetails function's response to the router file.
My router js file contains,

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();
 var app = require('../app');
 router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('add-category', { title: 'Express' });
 });

module.exports = router;
```

Can you help me in this?

Comment: Can you clarify what means "send the above function's response to the router file"

Comment: I mean to say path.getDetails() @iofjuupasli

Comment: in your code `'/query:arg1/:arg2'` and `router.get('/'` are two different routes why do you want one routes response available different route?

Comment: Actually I need to pass the response to the html page without using AJAX. So I'm trying to pass it via routes file. @ZeeshanHassanMemon

Comment: Instead tell here what you need actually so that we can guide you accordingly

Comment: I need to send a response data from app.js to html file without making an ajax call. Can you please suggest me how to do it? @ZeeshanHassanMemon

Comment: Don't understand what you exactly mean by that but you can see ejs or jade template engines, then for example you can pass some data to `res.render('add-category', { title: 'Express', otherData: {.....} });` and ejs/jade will display it in your html file to client.

Comment: can i use res.render('add-category', path.getDetails(req,res)) ? @ZeeshanHassanMemon

Comment: no no --it's not like that! Umm for idea may be you can see this https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/4f0aff7716885b7d4404a17ac89a4c8299bcb2a4/random/small_tasks/express_server

Comment: Its best if you provide the js file containing getDetails. Please provide all relevant files so we can help you more efficiently.